# Simple problem with Class RandomEvent in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

I create a simple text quest with random events, which accumulated a lot, and I decided to separate them into a separate class. But after that I got a problem. It doesn't look complicated, but I can't find a solution.

```
import random


class Hero:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


hero1 = Hero('Bob')


class RandEvents:
    def __init__(self, hero):
        self.hero = hero

    def event1(self):
        print(f'>>> {self.hero.name} text 1 event! <<<')

    def event2(self):
        print(f'>>> {self.hero.name} text 2 event! <<<')


list_events = [RandEvents.event1, RandEvents.event2]
event = random.choice(list_events)
event(hero1)
```

I get

```
  File "E:\1.py", line 17, in event1
    print(f'>>> {self.hero.name} text 1 event! <<<')
                 ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Hero' object has no attribute 'hero'
```

I tried to create a function `rand_event()`, and move it to a class `Hero` or `RandEvents`. To no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
import random


class Hero:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


hero1 = Hero('Bob')


class RandEvents:
    def __init__(self, hero):
        self.hero = hero

    def event1(self):
        print(f'>>> {self.name} text 1 event! <<<')

    def event2(self):
        print(f'>>> {self.name} text 2 event! <<<')


list_events = [RandEvents.event1, RandEvents.event2]
event = random.choice(list_events)
event(hero1)
```

Comment: Yes, it work. Thanks! I tried such an edition myself, but the PyCharm allocated me such syntax as a mistake! >_< Sorry for the stupid question.